# value of \thepage in \markright is always 1

Tags: sectioning, counters, article

The following latex input:

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \pagestyle{myheadings}

 \markright{\ifodd\thepage ODD HEADER on \thepage\else EVEN HEADER on \thepage\fi}
```

outputs "ODD HEADER on 1" on all pages, apparently because \thepage is 1 when \markright is executed. How can I fix this (preferably without using fancyhdrs)?

Comment: the whole reason tex has a `\mark` system at all  because you can not test page numbers within the page.  `\markright` already means "use this if it ends on a right (odd) page" so what is the `ifodd` intended to test?

Comment: Use `\pageno` instead of `\thepage`. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

`\markright` expand its argument. In the time you wrote the line

```
\markright{\ifodd\thepage ODD HEADER on \thepage\else EVEN HEADER on \thepage\fi}
```

`\thepage` was equal 1, so after expansion the information the is stored in the node is `ODD HEADER on 1`.

You can solve that by storing `\ifodd\thepage ODD HEADER on \thepage\else EVEN HEADER on \thepage\fi` in a protected macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\NewDocumentCommand\Tim{}{\ifodd\thepage ODD HEADER on \thepage\else EVEN HEADER on \thepage\fi}
\markright{\Tim}


\begin{document}
 hello \newpage  hello\newpage hello
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained already `\markright` expands at time of definition.  Here is syntax for legacy LaTeX.  Although `\ifodd` is I presume not official LaTeX, it is core TeX (hence I allowed myself `\noexpand` which is not LaTeX either).

```latex
\documentclass{article}

% only for screenshot purposes
\usepackage[paperheight=4cm,height=2cm,includehead,nofoot]{geometry}


 \pagestyle{myheadings}

 \markright{\noexpand\ifodd\value{page}%
     ODD HEADER on \protect\thepage
     \noexpand\else
     EVEN HEADER on \protect\thepage
     \noexpand\fi}
\begin{document}
A
\clearpage
B
\clearpage
C 
\end{document}
```

Mind that I avoided `\thepage` in the `\ifodd` test as `\thepage` is not guaranteed to be compatible with TeX numerical context.

[image: 3 pages with headers]